# How do you properly configure Ruby on Rails local dev environment for working with aws xray open telemetry sdk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, aws-xray, otel

I am trying to figure out how to properly setup a local dev environment to test my tracing. However, I am running into this error: `OpenTelemetry error: unexpected configuration error due to uninitialized constant Trace - OpenTelemetry::SDK::ConfigurationError`

Here is my initializer:

```
require 'opentelemetry-api'
require 'opentelemetry-exporter-otlp'
require 'opentelemetry-sdk'
require 'opentelemetry-propagator-xray'

OpenTelemetry::SDK.configure do |c|
    c.service_name = 'test-app'
    
    c.span_processors = [
      Trace::Export::BatchSpanProcessor.new(
          OpenTelemetry::Exporter::OTLP::Exporter.new(
            endpoint="localhost:2000"
          )
      )
    ]


    c.id_generator = OpenTelemetry::Propagator::XRay::IDGenerator
    c.propagators = [OpenTelemetry::Propagator::XRay::TextMapPropagator.new]
  
    c.use 'OpenTelemetry::Instrumentation::AwsSdk', {
      suppress_internal_instrumentation: true
    }
  
    c.use 'OpenTelemetry::Instrumentation::Rails'
    c.use 'OpenTelemetry::Instrumentation::Rack'
    c.use 'OpenTelemetry::Instrumentation::ActionPack'
    c.use 'OpenTelemetry::Instrumentation::ActiveSupport'
    c.use 'OpenTelemetry::Instrumentation::ActionView'
    c.use 'OpenTelemetry::Instrumentation::ActiveRecord'
  
    c.use 'OpenTelemetry::Instrumentation::Faraday'
  end
```

And Gemfile:

```
# Use aws x-ray otel exporter
gem 'opentelemetry-exporter-otlp'
gem 'opentelemetry-sdk'

gem 'opentelemetry-propagator-xray'

gem 'opentelemetry-instrumentation-aws_sdk', '~> 0.2.1'
gem 'opentelemetry-instrumentation-faraday', '~> 0.19'
gem 'opentelemetry-instrumentation-rails', '~> 0.20'
```

I am using a local Docker setup and can confirm that everything is working correctly. I think I am missing something in this configuration altogether

Answer (score 0):

Is because the documentation is not up-to-date with the gem versions.
Encountered a few issues myself (3):

- `c.add_span_processor() instead of c.span_processors = []`
- Missing namespace: `OpenTelemetry::SDK::Trace::Export::BatchSpanProcessor.new`
- Not specifying path of endoint: `/v1/traces`

Try:

```rb
  # The X-Ray ID Generator generates spans with X-Ray backend compliant IDs
  c.id_generator = OpenTelemetry::Propagator::XRay::IDGenerator

  # The X-Ray Propagator injects the X-Ray Tracing Header into downstream calls
  c.propagators = [OpenTelemetry::Propagator::XRay::TextMapPropagator.new]

  # Set collector
  c.add_span_processor(
    # Use the BatchSpanProcessor to send traces in groups instead of one at a time
    OpenTelemetry::SDK::Trace::Export::BatchSpanProcessor.new(
      # Use the default OLTP Exporter to send traces to the ADOT Collector
      OpenTelemetry::Exporter::OTLP::Exporter.new(
        # The ADOT Collector is running as a sidecar and listening on port 4317
        endpoint: "http://aws-ot-collector:4317/v1/traces"
      )
    )
  )
```

ScoutApm has a very good [article](https://scoutapm.com/blog/configuring-opentelemetry-in-ruby) on OpenTelemetry configuration for Rails.